# Obtain a unique ID from a different dataframe

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
First.Name  Last.Name   Country   Unit  Hospital
  John        Mars        UK     Sales   South
  John        Mars        UK     Sales   South
  John        Mars        UK     Sales   South
  Lisa        Smith       USA    HHRR    North
  Lisa        Smith       USA    HHRR    North
```

and this other:

```
First.Name  Last.Name   ID
 John        Valjean    1254
 Peter       Smith      1255
 Frank       Mars       1256
 Marie       Valjean    1257
 Lisa        Smith      1258
 John        Mars       1259
```

and I would like to merge them or paste them together to have:
[image]

I tried with `x = merge(df1, df2, by.y=c('Last.Name','First.Name')` but it doesnt seem to work. also with `x = df1[c(df1$Last.Name, df1$First.Name) %in% c(df2$Last.Name, df2$First.Name),]` and it also doesnt work.

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by = c('First.Name', 'Last.Name'))` works fine for me

Comment: In `dplyr`, you can also do `df1 %>%
 left_join(df2, by = c("First.Name" = "First.Name",
                       "Last.Name" = "Last.Name"))`.

Comment: With `merge(df1, df2, by = c('First.Name', 'Last.Name'))` I get an empty df...

Comment: It worked with `dplyr`. Thank you!!

Comment: `merge` works for me too. Something else is wrong.

Comment: The merge might not work if the columns in the two dataframes are of different types - perhaps one of `df1$First.Name` and `df2$First.Name` is a factor and the other is character, for example.  To check, do `str(df1)`, which will tell you the variable types.  If so, try converting all of the merging columns to character first using `as.character` before the merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `merge`, hou have to be careful with its arguments, especially with `by`, `by.x`, `by.y`, `all`, `all.x` and `all.y`. The description of each of these arguments is available [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html)

Based on this, try out:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c('First.Name', 'Last.Name')) # see @Sotos's comment
# output
  First.Name Last.Name Country  Unit Hospital   ID
1       John      Mars      UK Sales    South 1259
2       John      Mars      UK Sales    South 1259
3       John      Mars      UK Sales    South 1259
4       Lisa     Smith     USA  HHRR    North 1258
5       Lisa     Smith     USA  HHRR    North 1258

merge(df1, df2, by.x = c('Last.Name','First.Name'),
      by.y = c('Last.Name','First.Name')) # in you code, you set by.y but not by.x
# output
  Last.Name First.Name Country  Unit Hospital   ID
1      Mars       John      UK Sales    South 1259
2      Mars       John      UK Sales    South 1259
3      Mars       John      UK Sales    South 1259
4     Smith       Lisa     USA  HHRR    North 1258
5     Smith       Lisa     USA  HHRR    North 1258

# by in dplyr::left_join() works like by in merge()
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = c('First.Name', 'Last.Name')) # see @tmfmnk's comment
# output
  First.Name Last.Name Country  Unit Hospital   ID
1       John      Mars      UK Sales    South 1259
2       John      Mars      UK Sales    South 1259
3       John      Mars      UK Sales    South 1259
4       Lisa     Smith     USA  HHRR    North 1258
5       Lisa     Smith     USA  HHRR    North 1258
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(First.Name = c("John", "John", "John", "Lisa", 
"Lisa"), Last.Name = c("Mars", "Mars", "Mars", "Smith", "Smith"
), Country = c("UK", "UK", "UK", "USA", "USA"), Unit = c("Sales", 
"Sales", "Sales", "HHRR", "HHRR"), Hospital = c("South", "South", 
"South", "North", "North")), .Names = c("First.Name", "Last.Name", 
"Country", "Unit", "Hospital"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(First.Name = c("John", "Peter", "Frank", "Marie", 
"Lisa", "John"), Last.Name = c("Valjean", "Smith", "Mars", "Valjean", 
"Smith", "Mars"), ID = 1254:1259), .Names = c("First.Name", "Last.Name", 
"ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```